# Cannot ping github in OSX Sierra

Tags: git, github, cocoapods

Im trying to clone a github repo for cocoapods but i can't even ping github.

```
ping: cannot resolve https://github.com: Unknown host
```

Comment: Can you ping _any_ URL succesfully?  Maybe this isn't a GitHub problem at all.

Comment: Yes i can ping any url with http but i cant ping https websites

Answer (score 1):

`https://github.com` is not a host name, it's a URL.

The host is `github.com`.

On my computer I get:

```
$ ping https://github.com
ping: cannot resolve https://github.com: Unknown host

$ ping github.com
PING github.com (192.30.253.113): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.30.253.113: icmp_seq=0 ttl=43 time=110.597 ms
```

Comment: My problem is after type command pod install i get this error

Comment: Unable to add a source with url `https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git` named `master`

Comment: Your question was about ping.