# Hexo deploy: No connection to Github

Tags: github, proxy, hexo

When I try to deploy my Hexo blog to Github, I cannot get access to Github. And I also cannot get access to Github via Safari.
Here is a bug report
`Proxy CONNECT aborted`
I am using the latest macOS.

Comment: I stop proxy via `git config --global --unset http.proxy`.
And I try `ping github.com`, but it fails.

Answer (score 0):

`git config` might not be enough, if you also have an HTTP_PROXY/HTTP_PROXY environment variable in your session.

Hexo has a [troubleshooting page](https://hexo.io/docs/troubleshooting.html), but if you cannot even ping github.com:

- that is the first issue to resolve (since [github.com status itself is fine](https://www.githubstatus.com/))
- check if you can ping anything else (google.com?)
- make sure your are [not pinging https://github.com](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40172918/6309)
- check if pinging the IP works (as [in this article](https://www.programmersought.com/article/89284854980/)n which then modified the `/private/etc/hosts`)

Comment: I managed to ping github.com:

```PING github.com (13.229.188.59): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 13.229.188.59: icmp_seq=0 ttl=43 time=104.014 ms
...
--- github.com ping statistics ---
11 packets transmitted, 11 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
```
But I still can not deploy my blog via `hexo d`.
```fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/ymlkzp/ymlkzp.github.io.git/': Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Operation timed out
```
I checked hexo troubleshooting page, but it didn't help.

Comment: OK. Did you check your environment variables? Your Safari settings? Is there any trace of a proxy setting set anywhere?

Comment: I checked my environment variables and host. I am quite sure there is no trace of proxy setting.

Comment: @Cino OK. What command do you type, and what error message do you get?

Comment: I just tried git clone. It didn't work either. So I am afraid it is not the problem of Safari.

Comment: @Cino Yes but what is the exact command typed? And error message?

Comment: Well, I just go out for a while. When I come back, it just works>_<. Thanks for help!